# Converting a number into a string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, numbers

So I had an assignment about adding up all the digits of a number. For example if the number is 2367, add 2 + 3 + 6 + 7.

However, the problem is that the number is huge (2^325) which is around 106 digits. I tried using double or float but the problem is that the number appears only as 0's after like 10 digits or so of being precise.

The other problem I have is that I don't know if I should convert the number to a string or an array and then add up all of the positions of the string or the array (like array[1] + array[2] + ... array[n]).

If I'm correct, how can i convert a number to an array/string?

Thank you! I only learned C so I'm not even sure how to change this in C++

Beginner programmer here :(

Thanks again!

Comment: Just read the digits as characters, convert each to a number (`digit-'0'`) and add it to your sum.

Comment: This problem goes away entirely if you treat them as "digits" instead of "digits of a single, huge number"

Comment: @Jerry Coffin
How can i convert a lets say double or float into characters itself? Should I convert them to a string or an array? Or as you mentioned to digits? Sorry, I'm pretty new so I don't have a good idea as to what you mean.

Comment: @Drew Dormann
Wouldn't it be the same to treat them as different digits and digits of a number since I'll be adding them up separately anyways?

Comment: I'm advising that you never try to convert the string of digits into a number. Just read a digit, compute the value of that one digit, add it to your sum, and repeat for the remaining digits. If you were to convert to a number, you'd immediately convert the result back to individual digits anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to keep your number as an `std::string`.  The `std::string` can be accessed like an array.

To convert a numerical character, such as '3', to a number, subtract the character '0' from it.
Example:

```
unsigned int value_of_3 = '3' - '0';
```

To add up all the digits, loop through the string, character by character.  For each numerical character, subtract '0', then add the result to a sum variable.

**Edit 1:**
Illustrative drawings.
Given the number 2367 as string "2367", you have the array:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+  
| '2' | '3' | '6' | '7' |  
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Let the string be named `digit_string`.
The value `digit_string[1]` has the value of '3' as in the diagram above.

To get the numeric value of the 2nd slot:

```
unsigned numeric_value = digit_string[1] - '0';
```

This results in `numeric_value == 3;`.

Comment: I have a question though, if my number is a double (2^352) then should i put it something like this:
double value = pow (2, 352)
because what I dont get is how can i convert pow(2, 352) into a string so that my value[0] = x and value [1] =y etc etc to add them up?

Comment: The number 2^352 is not a double, it is an integer.  With the method I presented above, you are inputting the number as a string, NOT as a double or integer, but as a string.

Comment: Ohhh okay, I see what you mean.
I still have a doubt though, when defining it as an integer, how can i define pow (2, 352) as a string since I don't have all 102 values to define it as a string since the beginning. I'm really sorry for all the confusion, since I'm new to this I really have a lot of doubts still

Comment: See my `Edit 2`.  Also, read carefully the code, as the digit string should be assigned using characters, such as `std::string digit_string = "2367";`

Comment: If you are using numbers that exceed the capacity of C++ largest variable, you will need to use a Big Number library.

Comment: By the way, when raising 2 to a power, you should use the left shift operator, which is more efficient than the `pow` function.  To my understanding representing 2^352 requires an integer that is 352-bits.  I don't know of any processors that can internally represent this.  So you will need a Big Number library.

Comment: Very, very nice looking answer! (The content is great too). +1 for the nice ASCII art :) and for this clever solution. This is a very cool way to achieve this! I would have never ever considered converting the number in a string to a real number this way! It's a very nice, simple hack that's not too "hacky", and I am going to save this example somewhere :).

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to the header question than the subsequent questions in the description. A simple way to convert a number to a string is to output the value to a stream and retrieve the string contents of the stream.

```
int streetNumber = 2500;
string streetNumberStr;
ostringstream os;
os << streetNumber;
streetNumberStr = os.str();
```